# Determine relevant parts of a boolean expression that cause evaluation to True

Tags: python, parsing, boolean, expression

Given that I have boolean expressions which I know will evaluate to `True` that have a number of variables (1...n) and I also know that (1...n) of the variables are `True`, how can I determine which of the `True` values actually had an impact on the expression (i.e. causing it to evaluate it to `True`)?

**Basic example**: let's assume I have `(A and B) or (C and D)` with `A = True`, `B = True` and `C = True`. In this case the value of `C` is irrelevant for the evaluation of the boolean expression as the right part of the expression always evaluates to false given `D = False`.

I would need a method (e.g. `find_relevant_values()`) to determine that `[A, B]` are relevant.

```
A = True
B = True
C = True
D = False
bool_exp = "(A and B) or (C and D)"
print(eval(bool_exp)) #True

# is this doable?
print(find_relevant_values(bool_exp)) #[A, B]
```

I would need a generic way (e.g. `find_relevant_values()`) to determine the relevant values. In the example above `[A, B]` are the relevant values.

Comment: Treat the true variables as variables, and treat the false variables as constants.  Then simplify.  For example:  `(A and B) or (C and D)` becomes `(A and B) or (C and False)`, which simplifies to `A and B`.

Comment: @TomKarzes what would you use  to do this simplification? The boolean expressions can be more complex e.g. consider negations

Comment: @fluxens You'll need to parse it if you want to do symbolic manipulation.  A simple recursive-descent expression parser should suffice.  You can probably write it in an hour or two.

Comment: Evaluate it once with each of its inputs negated. Any of them where the result is different are those that had an effect on the output.

Comment: @DanD. That won't work.  Suppose A, B, C, D are all true.  Then `(A and B) or (C and D)` will be true regardless of whether any single variable is inverted.  So your logic would deem all of them as having no effect, in spite of the expression being true.  An even simpler case is `A or B`.  If both of A, B are true, then either one of them can be inverted without changing the expression, yet clearly at least one of them must be true for the expression to be true.

Comment: @TomKarzes You are right. In this case the hypothetical method would need to return all as relevant .

Comment: What do you want for something like `A or not A`?  In this case, the result will be true regardless of what value `A` has.  The entire expression can be simplified to a constant `true`.  So does `A` contribute to the result?

Comment: @TomKarzes Depends: If `A == True`, then yes it does. If `A == False` it does not - by definition I only want to check which `True` values contributes to the whole expression being `True`.

Comment: @fluxens Ok, that's consistent.  On the other hand, `A and not A` would not mark `A` as relevant, since it always evaluates to false regardless of the value of `A`.  But `not (A and not A`)` would presumably mark `A` as relevant if `A` were true, since it always evaluates to true.

Comment: Neither "had an impact on the expression" nor "causing it to evaluate it to True" are clear. And are you actually interested is sets of inputs being "relevant" when all true or only individual inputs? PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score -1):

The solution below works in three steps: First, the input string is parsed to generate an expression tree. Second, the tree is traversed to find any instances of an `or` operator. If any of the `or` operands evaluate to `True`, the operand is either yielded if it is a terminal value (`A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`) or recursively traversed by `find_relevant`. Lastly, if no `or` operators are found, then the entire expression is evaluated and if the result is `True`, then the tree is traversed for all the relevant expressions that triggered the `True` value:

```
import re, collections as cl
m, op = {'A':True, 'B':True, 'C':True, 'D':False}, {'or':lambda x, y:x or y, 'and':lambda x, y:x and y}
#create the expression tree
def parse_expr(d):
   while (n:=next(d, None)) not in {None, ')'}:
     if n != '(':
        yield n
     else:
        yield list(parse_expr(d))

#evaluate the tree
def rel_eval(expr):
   while len(expr) > 1:
      _a, b, _c = [expr.popleft() for _ in range(3)]
      a = m.get(_a, _a) if not isinstance(_a, list) else rel_eval(collections.deque(_a))
      c = m.get(_c, _c) if not isinstance(_c, list) else rel_eval(collections.deque(_c))
      expr.appendleft(op[b](a, c))
   return expr[0]

#search for the relevant parts of the expression
def find_relevant(d):
   f = False
   for i in range(len(d)-1):
      if d[i] == 'or':
         f = True
         if (isinstance(d[i-1], list) and rel_eval(cl.deque(d[i-1]))) or (not isinstance(d[i-1], list) and m.get(d[i-1], False)):
             yield from ([d[i-1]] if not isinstance(d[i-1], list) else find_relevant(d[i-1]))
             break
         elif (isinstance(d[i+1], list) and rel_eval(cl.deque(d[i+1]))) or (not isinstance(d[i+1], list) and m.get(d[i+1], False)):
             yield from ([d[i+1]] if not isinstance(d[i+1], list) else find_relevant(d[i+1]))
             break
   if not f and rel_eval(cl.deque(d)):
      for i in filter(lambda x:x != 'and' and x != 'or', d):
          yield from ([i] if not isinstance(i, list) else find_relevant(i))
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
def find_relevant_values(s):
   #parse the input and create the tree
   r = list(parse_expr(iter(re.findall('\(|\)|\w+', s))))
   #consume the generator results from find_revelant
   return list(find_relevant(r))

print(find_relevant_values('(A and B) or (C and D)'))
print(find_relevant_values('(A and (B or C)) and (C or D)'))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```